# Too much li padding in communities list in Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, top-bar

Clicking the Stack Exchange button to show the list of communities whilst on [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) shows the list of communities, but with too much vertical padding:

> [image]

On Stack Overflow Careers, `li` has `padding-bottom: 7px;` causing this extra padding:

> [image]
>   [image]

<sup>Left: Stack Overflow Careers; Right: Stack Exchange</sup>

Could this extra padding be removed from the communities list dropdown?

Comment: Also, "Your Community" is wrong, should stay "Your Communities" like on all other sites.

Comment: Usually the careers team responds quickly, wonder why they ignore this bug which while doesn't break anything, is really ugly.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. We'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, all. Should be fixed now.