# careers-specific "Find a StackExchange community" bug (dropdown disappears)

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, top-bar

On Firefox 38 for Linux Mint, I am having an issue at careers.se but not at meta.se.

If I click the StackExchange dropdown, then click inside the "Find a StackExchange community" input box, instead of leaving the dropdown open and putting keyboard focus inside the input box, the dropdown immediately closes.

Comment: Reproduced... and it looks like the styling is a bit off as well. The rows are taller than they should be.

Comment: Well, the Careers top bar drop down has many bugs, looks like they tried to build their own copy and kind of failed. See [this other bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257204/too-much-li-padding-in-communities-list-in-stack-overflow-careers), which didn't get any attention either. /cc @Anna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

We share the top bar's HTML with the rest of the Stack Exchange sites, but not its JavaScript. A recent change caused clicks inside the dropdown to close it.

Even if that hadn't happened, the textbox had not JavaScript attached to it and so wouldn't do anything. So I implemented that as well.